Launching a cross chain ERC20
I would like to launch a cross-chain basic ERC20 token on ethereum's layer 2 networks. Is there an dapp that let's me do this ? If I understand well in order to make this happen I only need to deploy the contracts at the same address and that's it ?

As the OP asked for a tool to deploy an ERC20, as an example, it is possible to use Thirdweb to do this: https://thirdweb.com/thirdweb.eth/TokenERC20.
As Spaguetti mentioned, you simply have to deploy your ERC20 on the chains that you want to support. Just make sure that you allow for mint/burn/wrap functions when needed.

You can't launch coins cross chain. For example, Arbitrum $MAGIC is different to ETH $MAGIC. If you're referring to deploying a token on each chain, you would simply follow the steps to launch your ERC-20 on the individual chains. In addition you could swap your tokens from one to the other using something like SushiSwap, but it would still be different tokens.

I don't understand the downvotes, on what seems a reasoned response. If someone downvoted this and isn't a bot, it could be of value to leave behind the reasoning, as it pertains to review. Cheers

@Maka No, not a bot haha... I don' t get it either... I answered the question correctly (afaik).

Yes agree. I upvoted at the time, but you had already received 3 downvotes before that. Which made them seem suspect to me. Maybe some question/answer farming that you interrupted, I don't know.
